# How to compare an installation path with a wildcarded application name in python

Tags: python, path, wildcard

I want to traverse a dataframe in python and, by this, to get rid of the full installation path. So only the application name, e.g. firefox.exe or firefox shall be explicated and not "C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe".

I created a function which takes the respective dataframe and a dcitonary containing key value pairs with a application name as key (firefox) and the wildcarded path as value (*firefox.exe).

```
def transform_process_name(mid_result_df, name_dict):
    for row, col in mid_result_df.iterrows():
        for name, value in name_dict.items():
            print(name)
            print(value)
            if col['ProcessName'] == value:
                col['ProcessName'] = name

    return mid_result_df
```

this is called in a function as follows:

```
transform_process_name(mid_result_df, __name_of_processes)
```

where

```
__name_of_processes =
{
    'firefox': '*firefox.exe',
}
```

The comparison does not work. so the output is still "C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" and not "firefox".

Thank you :)

**EDIT:**
It now works with

```
def transform_process_name(mid_result_df, name_dict):

    for row, col in mid_result_df.iterrows():
        for name, value in name_dict.items():
            string_check = col['ProcessName']
            if string_check.endswith(value):
                mid_result_df.at[row, 'ProcessName'] = name
    return mid_result_df
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can use `==` to compare "C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" and "*firefox.exe". I think you probably want to replace

```
if col['ProcessName'] == value:
```

with

```
if value in col['ProcessName']:
```

or

```
if col['ProcessName'].endswith(value):
```

and `value` should be 'firefox.exe'.

**EDIT**:

This is my code:

```
import pandas as pd

def transform_process_name(mid_result_df, name_dict):
    for row, col in mid_result_df.iterrows():
        for name, value in name_dict.items():
            if value in col['ProcessName']:
            # if col['ProcessName'].endswith(value):
                col['ProcessName'] = name
            else:
                col['ProcessName'] = col['ProcessName']
    return mid_result_df


mid_result_df = pd.DataFrame({'ProcessName': ['C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe']})
name_dict = {'firefox': 'firefox.exe'}

result = transform_process_name(mid_result_df, name_dict)
print(result)
```

Comment: hey thank you, I put my version into the edit... it did not work unfortunately :(

Comment: Hello @gero, I just updated my answer. I think the problem is that `value` should not include `*`

Comment: Hey thanks your first answer was fine, I just did a small mistake - thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I did not understand well the problem, but if you have a dataframe containing the paths to each application, why don't you use the native functions in the `os` module to extract the name of the application themselves?

For example:

```
import pandas as pd
import os


def get_application(path):
    return os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(path))[0]


path = "C:/Program Files/Mozilla Firefox/"
df = pd.DataFrame([os.path.join(path + "firefox.exe"), os.path.join(path + "myapp.exe")],
                  columns=["full_path"])

df["application"] = df["full_path"].apply(get_application)

print(df)
```

Here, I created a dummy dataframe with paths to the applications. Then I define a function that given a path, returns only the app name (`basename`) without the dot (`splitext`).
The apply method applies the function to each element of the dataframe, and the output is stored in a new column.

Result:

```
                                      full_path application
0  C:/Program Files/Mozilla Firefox/firefox.exe     firefox
1    C:/Program Files/Mozilla Firefox/myapp.exe       myapp
```

Comment: the problem is that I will have to deal with varying paths which are sent to me in this dataframe, so I will have to rely upon the dataframe solution without deploying the os solution :(